# How to let users attend events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an app, sort of like meetup.com, users can create events, comment on the events, search the events by GPS radius.. However, I'd like to allow users to click on an 'Attend' button and then on the events/show.html.erb page show which users are attending etc...

How might I do this?

**current event show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/header' %>                                                                                                                                 

<div class="container">                                                                                                                                       
  <div class="row">                                                                                                                                           
    <div class="span3">                                                                                                                                       
      <%= render 'sidebar' %>                                                                                                                                 
    </div>                                                                                                                                                    
    <div class="span5">                                                                                                                                       
      <div class="new_event_form">                                                                                                                            
        <div class="line1"><h4>Create event</h4></div>                                                                                                        
        <%= form_for current_user.events.new, remote: true do |f| %>                                                                                          
          <h5>Event title:</h5>                                                                                                                               
          <div><%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Event title", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                               
          <h5>Event description:</h5>                                                                                                                         
          <div><%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Event description", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                    
          <h5>Event date:</h5>                                                                                                                                
          <div><%= f.text_field :date  %></div>                                                                                                               
          <h5>Event location:</h5>                                                                                                                            
          <div><%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: "Event location", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                         
          <div>                                                                                                                                               
            <%= f.submit "Create event", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>                                                                                          
            <%= link_to "Cancel", '#', class: 'btn cancel_event' %>                                                                                           
          </div><br />                                                                                                                                        
        <% end %>                                                                                                                                             
      </div>                                                                                                                                                  
      <div class="events_list">                                                                                                                               
        <!-- look in events/event.hmlt.erb -->                                                                                                                
        <h4><%= @event.title %> at <%= @event.location %></h4>                                                                                                
        <p><%= @event.description %></p>                                                                                                                      
        <h5><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <%= @event.date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y") %></h5>                                                                
        <h5><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <%= @event.time %></h5>                                                                                             
        <h5><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <%= @event.location %></h5>                                                                                      
      </div>                                                                                                                                                  
      <div class="name"></div>                                                                                                                                

            <%= form_for [@commentable, @comment], remote: true do |f| %> 
...........and so on...
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: What specifically do you have a problem with?

Comment: Thanks Amadan, basically - writing the code to allow users to RSVP, can't think of what it should be and how it should work..

Comment: Also... why is this marked both `ruby-on-rails-4` and `ruby-on-rails-3`?

Comment: Whoops, guess I went click happy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define 'attend' action in your routes.rb and your Event controller, and then create attend.html.erb form for it.

Edit: in routes.rb

```
 resources :events do
   post 'attend', on: :member
 end
```

in events_controller

```
def attend
  @event.attendees << current_user
  @event.save
end
```

in show.html.erb somewhere

```
 <%= button_to 'Attend', attend_event_path(@event), method: :post, confirm: 'really?' %>
```

and make a nice attend.html.erb to say "thanks for signing up"

Comment: What's in the form though?

Comment: Don't really need a form, a `button_to` on the `show` should be enough.

Comment: Will also need a new `has_and_belongs_to_many` between events and attendees.

Comment: I'd create attendance record in the Event controller and then show some confirmation like 'Thanks for signing up for this awesome event #94879'.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @DeeY. Once I've got that down, how could I display attendee's i.e. '5 people are attending this event'

Comment: where do you want to show it? After the user signs up or before?

Comment: after the user signs up

Comment: in the attend.html.erb just output @event.attendees.count somewhere

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much DeeY. Is there a way that I can do =link_to @event.attendees.count, and then show which actual users are attending? maybe like.. <%=link_to (at)event.attendees.count, event_attendees_path(users) %>

Comment: check that it is 'on: :member'

Comment: Perfect, that was it! Thanks @DeeY. Can i show which users are attending? I have something like: (There are <%= link_to (at)event.participants.size, (at)event_participants %> attendees attending this event) but it just links back to the event page. I'd like it so when you click on the number of users attending it'll show which actual users i.e Jack is attending, Jackie is attending etc..

Comment: So you want the list of attendees on a separate page? Or shown right there? In any case, I'd probably define another action like "get /event/:id/attendees' and a corresponding method in the controller. Then you can either show it on a separate page or load via ajax

Comment: That is great, thanks so much..It's working perfectly, the only thing now to complete it is to allow users to 'Stop attending'

Comment: very similar to attend, I guess :)

Comment: resources :events do 
    post 'stop_attend', on: :member
  end  <%= button_to 'Stop attending this Event', stop_attend_event_path(@event), method: :post %>

Comment: that, and a method in controller